# No space left on device (linux /tmp)

Tags: linux

I am new to linux.

I hope to install openvpn on my dedicated server.
When I maked lzo/openvpn project, it said that there are 2 error, the reason is'No space left on device'
I checked /tmp directory. The /tmp patrition space limitation is 1012M , used 925M

It looks like the directory/partrition is almost full.

What is the solution for this?
clear /tmp directory or any other way?

Welcome any comment

Thanks
interdev

Answer (score 4):

For ways of safely tidying up /tmp, have a look at [Wipe out /tmp every week?](https://serverfault.com/questions/201164/wipe-out-tmp-every-week/) .  Failing that, use `du -sk /tmp/* | sort -n` to identify the big files and subdirectories in your /tmp, and think carefully about what you can safely remove before doing so.  There's no magic recipe to identifying what's safe to remove, but common sense and careful thought will help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You might also investigate if there is a binary package by the Distribution your Linux installation is based.

OpenVPN should be pretty common in modern distros.

*Nothing to do with the primary question but might be helpful anyway*

Comment: I used different version to install, same report

Answer (score 0):

This belongs on superuser, however you should just clear /tmp.

Answer (score 0):

Could  you sort files by size  to view  what  is fulling   your /tmp   maybe some softwere  usuing space on /tmp for logs

Answer (score 0):

You could clear this directory :

```
echo "Emptying /tmp"
rm /tmp/* -rf &1>2 > /dev/null
```

You could also set TMPTIME=7 in /etc/default/rcS so that only stuff older than 7 days is deleted when you reboot.

Comment: Will the files in /tmp be removed automatically when rebooting the server?

Comment: yes, with TMPTIME=7 files older than 7 days are automatically deleted every reboot

Comment: it depends on the distro.

Answer (score 0):

can you run "df -k /tmp" - is /tmp on the "/" filesystem , or is it on its own filesystem ?
If it is on the "/" filesystem , its perfectly reasonable for it to be as large as this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't know what files in /tmp may be in use by the system. Reboot first, then delete any files pre-dating the reboot from /tmp (or anything more than 1 day old). Then for good measure, reboot again.

Although for the longer term, you need to start keeping an eye on what files are in /tmp and work out why they're not getting cleared down automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot the server 
Then execute 
find /tmp -mtime +1 -delete 
This will safely delete any file older than 1 day in your /tmp 
If this is still not enough open the file /etc/fstab and comment the line referring to tmp 
Reboot 
Now your tmp doesn't use a separate partition and it is writing on the root drive. 
Try to install again. 
Revert the changes in /etc/fstab once you are done. 
If you are still facing the same problem after this then you should really make some space.